# Is it possible to build MarkupString with provided Action?

Tags: c#, blazor

When you work with raw HTML within Blazor you write for example:

```
<div style="  display: flex;align-items: center;"  @onclick="@Toggle">
...
</div>
```

"Toggle" here is method (`Action`). I would like to extract such piece of code into helper function creating MarkupString. Something like this:

```
MarkupString HelperBuild(Action action)
{
    return new MarkupString(@$"<div style='display: flex;align-items: center;' 
        @onclick=??????>....");
}
```

Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: You should avoid `MarkupString` unless it is the only possible solution, as it exposes you to XSS attacks unless you actively sanitize the strings.  Using `RenderFragment` instead is the way to go, except your HTML is malformed since the `<div>` tag is unclosed.  If you actually have arbitrary child content for the `div`, you're probably better off writing a normal component.

Comment: @KirkWoll, thank you. This is static html, no input from the user. As for closing div, ok, I closed it, here I focus on action :-). I will try components as well, but they are overkill for simple one-liners.

Comment: My point about the `<div>` being unclosed is that you presumably actually have child content, right?  i.e. in your realworld use-case, there will be content between `<div>` and `</div>`?  And since you are not passing in that content to `HelperBuild`, I am assuming you are doing something like `@HelperBuild(myAction) some child content </div>`?  If instead you are expecting `HelperBuild` to provide the child content, then a `RenderFragment` will work great for your needs.  If you can confirm that, I'd be happy to provide an answer.

Comment: @KirkWollm in this case everything is properly enclosed (in real code) and I do pass child content indeed :-) but it is basic string (a title). The background of this question is  more complicated though -- I try to build pretty long html list, and I would like to apply re-use principles while keeping entire code minimal. But I already hit several issues with mixing components with code (reported), and so I reorganized my code into using void-renderers. Now when the code grows I try to find the way out maybe using MarkupString. Probably this is dead-end so I try also 1-line components.

Comment: @KirkWoll The reports if you are interested https://github.com/dotnet/razor-compiler/issues/249 and
https://github.com/dotnet/razor-compiler/issues/250

Comment: Hmm, those github issues indicate attempts to have a `void` return type for your renderer.  Why would you not just return `RenderFragment` and call your function like `@HelperBuild(myAction)` in your HTML?  I'll provide an answer with a solution, and maybe we can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RenderFragment` should work fine for your purposes.

```
RenderFragment HelperBuild(string childContent, Action action)
{
    return @<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;" @onclick="action">
        @childContent
    </div>;
}
```

Then you can in your razor markup just use it like:

```
@HelperBuild("My Child Content", () => Console.WriteLine("foo"))
```

Note that unlike the GitHub issue you referenced, the above line should not be in the `code` block as that won't do anything.  It should be alongside the rest of the markup for your page.

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks promising and I hope I dig out from my problems :-). I was under impression one needs to work with html tree builder.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation around this usage pattern of `RenderFragment` could be improved.  I learned about it from [this Blazor performance document](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/1e199f340780f407a685695e6c4d953f173fa891/aspnetcore/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices.md#defining-reusable-renderfragments-in-code).  It's a very useful document if you haven't seen it yet.